# How to Add id to each element based on the count in JQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="tile_nav">
<ul>
<li><span class="ullevel2"><span>Sample text</span></span></li>
<li><span class="ullevel2"><span>Sample text</span></span></li>
<li><span class="ullevel2"><span>Sample text</span></span></li>
<li><span class="ullevel2"><span>Sample text</span></span></li>        
</ul>   
</div>
```

I have used

```
$(".tile_nav .ullevel2 span").attr('id', function(index) {
return "testDiv" + ($(this).index() + 1);
});
```

How to add id to each element based on the length by jQuery each on page loading?
https://jsfiddle.net/4LLocqau/1/

Comment: `$(this).index()` will always be zero.

Comment: Just wondering, why would you need to add ID to each `span`?

Comment: Agree with ^^^, However this might help https://jsfiddle.net/d0fwdjs9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```
var cnt = 1;
$(".tile_nav .ullevel2 span").each(function () {
    $(this).attr('id', function (index) {
        return "testDiv" + cnt;
    });
    cnt++;
});
```

`.each()` is useful in your case to loop through the elements.

Working Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/4LLocqau/4/)

Comment: The each loop and `cnt` variable are useless here: https://jsfiddle.net/4LLocqau/5/

Comment: agreed. that will be the same as Tahir's answer.

Comment: Not exactly, one less function call

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.tile_nav .ullevel2 span').each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('id', 'testDiv' + (index + 1));
});
```

***[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4LLocqau/2/)***.

You could use an [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) loop to iterate through the `span` objects. And this `each()` sends an `index` value that we can further utilise to form and apply an `id`.

I am assuming of course that you want to add `id` attribute to the inner-most `span` element. Correct me if I am wrong.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on this sample, it might help [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26znswza/5/).

```
$(".tile_nav .ullevel2 span").each(function( index ) {
   $(this).attr("id","testDiv" + (index+1));
   $(this).attr("title","id: 'testDiv"+(index+1)+"'"); //testing purpose
});
```